# IE li hover not detected with margins on the li element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, html-lists

I used the following css to make a child list inside a list display when you hover over the parent list item. In IE7&8 (but not ff and chrome) the space between the child li elements (provided by the line margin: 0.25em 0 0 0;) causes the browser to loose hover and hide the child list again. How can I fix this? Cheers.

The CSS I think is the cause:

```
#integratedSearchList li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

#integratedSearchList ul
{

    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    position:absolute;

    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;

    width:100%;
}

#integratedSearchList ul li
{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.25em 0 0 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: auto;
    width:90%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="integratedSearchContainer">
  <form id="integratedSearchForm" class="integratedSearchForm" action="..." method="get" name="integratedSearchForm">
    <ul id="integratedSearchList">
      <li>
        <label for="search" class="hidden">...</label> <input name="query" id="integratedSearchInput" hint="" type="text" maxlength="100" value=""> <button id="integratedSearchbutton" type="submit" class="enablehover" title=" Search ">Go</button>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a id="integratedAdvancedSearchHref" href="..." name="integratedAdvancedSearchHref">Advanced Search</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="seachSource1">...</label> <input id="seachSource1" name="source" type="checkbox" value="..."><br>
            <label for="seachSource2">...</label> <input id="seachSource2" name="source" type="checkbox" value="..."><br>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Complete CSS:

```
#integratedSearchContainer
{
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 1em 1.5em 0 0.75em;
    padding: 0;

    background: #ffffff;
}

#integratedSearchList
{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    background: #ffffff;

    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#integratedSearchList li
{
    width: inherit;
}

#integratedSearchList li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

#integratedSearchList ul
{

    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    position:absolute;

    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;

    width: 100%;
}

#integratedSearchList ul li
{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5%;
    margin: 0.25em 0 0 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
}

#integratedSearchList ul li:first-child > a
{
}

#integratedSearchList ul li:last-child > a
{
}

.integratedSearchForm {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.integratedSearchForm button, .integratedSearchForm .button {
    background: transparent url(../images/button_search.gif) no-repeat center top;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: none;
    text-indent: -1000em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.integratedSearchForm button:hover, .integratedSearchForm button.hover,
.integratedSearchForm .button:hover, .integratedSearchForm .button.hover {
    background-image: url(../images/button_search_feint.gif);
}

.integratedSearchForm button:disabled, .integratedSearchForm button.disabled,
.integratedSearchForm .button:disabled, .integratedSearchForm .button.disabled {
    background-image: url(../images/button_search_disabled.gif);
}

.integratedSearchForm #integratedSearchInput {
    border: none;
    margin: 2px 0.25em 2px 0.25em;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your HTML or recreating your issue on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I have half a feeling you aren't using a doctype. Are you? Which one?

Comment: HTML posted, sorry for having to remove some values - its work related. I don't think a doctype is set but its hard to tell because I'm not dealing with the HTML directly.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you state you don't think a doctype is set. This is probably the problem because you are in quirks mode and you will never get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers. Add a proper doctype, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>` and see if that doesn't fix IE.

If you don't have access to the HTML, you are in for a world of hurt since this will now require hack upon hack to beat IE into submission with the modern world.

Answer (score 0):

Why not avoid the issue altogether? Remove the margin from the li elements, and make them effectively transparent (no margin, border, etc..). Then use internal elements to actually form your menu structure (in your case maybe div, since your menu isn't just links). Once you have the internal elements in place, style those instead.

Maybe something like this:

```
<ul id="integratedSearchList">
  <li>
    <div class="menu-item">
    <label for="search" class="hidden">...</label> <input name="query" id="integratedSearchInput" hint="" type="text" maxlength="100" value="">
    <button id="integratedSearchbutton" type="submit" class="enablehover" title=" Search ">Go</button>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li> **//No margins or borders**
        <div class="menu-item"> **// Style borders, margins, etc.., here**
            <a id="integratedAdvancedSearchHref" href="..." name="integratedAdvancedSearchHref">Advanced Search</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="menu-item">
           <label for="seachSource1">...</label> <input id="seachSource1" name="source" type="checkbox" value="..."><br>
           <label for="seachSource2">...</label> <input id="seachSource2" name="source" type="checkbox" value="..."><br>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can take it even further by adding a CSS class to each "ul" element level, thus letting you customize the "menu-item" class even further.

Comment: Tried your second suggestion of wrapping the li content in a menu-item div and moving the padding etc. to this. Still the same behaviour exists even though the debug in IE shows that the <li> containers meet. Something do to with the background being transparent or somethng?

Comment: Just tested by adding a background on the li element and that stops the issue, which is annoying as I'd like the transparent space between the items.